# Cannot access ADLS from Synapse Analytics

Tags: azure-managed-identity, azure-synapse

I have;

1. A master key.
2. A database scoped credential.
3. An external data source.
4. File format.
5. A user created **managed identity** for Azure SQL Server.
6. RBAC **contributor** permission for that **managed identity** on my ADLS storage account.

When I execute the code to create an external table this **error** is raised:

> Failed to obtain the credential secret for the provided database and
>   credential. Database Name = DWShellDb, Credential Name =
>   devtechnicalpractice1_AdlsManagedIdentity, Exception =
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Fail to obtain or
>   decrypt secret for credential
>   'devtechnicalpractice1_AdlsManagedIdentity'.

This is the code:

```
CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL credname
WITH 
    IDENTITY = 'exact_mi_name'
;

CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE datasourcename
WITH
  ( LOCATION = 'abfss://containername@storageaccountname.dfs.core.windows.net' ,
    CREDENTIAL = credname ,
    TYPE = HADOOP
  ) ;

CREATE EXTERNAL FILE FORMAT Header_CSV1
WITH (FORMAT_TYPE = DELIMITEDTEXT,
      FORMAT_OPTIONS(
          FIELD_TERMINATOR = ',',
          STRING_DELIMITER = '"',
          FIRST_ROW = 1, 
          USE_TYPE_DEFAULT = True)
) ;


CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE [dbo].[tablename]
( [field1] VARCHAR(250) NULL,
  [field2] VARCHAR(250) NULL,
  [field3] VARCHAR(250) NULL )
WITH
(
    LOCATION='/Countries/' ,
    DATA_SOURCE = datasourcename,
    FILE_FORMAT = Header_CSV1 ,
    REJECT_TYPE = VALUE ,
    REJECT_VALUE = 0
) ;
```

I **do not** think the error lies within the TSQL but is security permission.

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue. Later I found out that I was missing secret while creating scoped credentials.
It should be something like this:

```
CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL credname
WITH
    IDENTITY = 'exact_mi_name',
    SECRET = 'adfNSkGPaTuryRdqt9sPAnjPW8xEzM7kQIYt' // data lake key
;
```

Comment: It has been a while since this problem arose. I got it working, I should have answered my own question. I have forgotten what changes I made.

Comment: @GettingItDone Hey man, I'm having the same issue and can't find anything online... Do you remember anything that might help?

Comment: Sorry @None I do not.